# Cannot create new BleManager in React Native app using Expo with react-native-ble-plx

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

## Can't Create New BleManager.

hello guys,

I'm making a React Native app to control an ESP32 device using the react-native-ble-plx library. I have cloned and modified the [BLESampleExpo example project](https://github.com/friyiajr/BLESampleExpo), and I added a welcome screen when the user opens the application after that I can click on "get started", to go to the project screen: [Welcome Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2BF1.jpg).

the app works fine on the welcome page. However, when I go to the other screen, I get the following error:
[The Error Message From Expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU71Y.jpg).

```
Render Error: Cannot read property 'createClient' of null
```

---

I have tried commenting out parts of the code to know from where the issue, and I think the problem is coming from this line of code:

```js
const bleManager = useMemo(() => new BleManager(), []);
```

---

Can anyone please help me solve this error?

I have found a lot of Stack Overflow questions about the same problem, but none of them have solved it. Is the react-native-ble-plx library **still working**? If not, what other library **should** I use?

Comment: I think the error is from node_modules/react-native-ble-plx/src/BleManager.js in line 92:

`BleModule.createClient(options.restoreStateIdentifier || null);`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and fixed it after following the config plugin `react-native-ble-plx` installation guide from [this blog](https://blog.theodo.com/2023/07/ble-integration-for-rn-apps/) and running the development server instead of Expo Go.

To summarize:

1. After adding this config in the `app.config.js` or `app.json` file:

```
    ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx",
        {
          "isBackgroundEnabled": true,
          "modes": [
            "peripheral",
            "central"
          ],
          "bluetoothAlwaysPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to connect to bluetooth devices"
        }
      ]
    ],
    ...
```

2. Run `expo prebuild`
3. Create a development build `npx eas build --profile development`
4. Scan the QR code, install the app on your phone and run it
5. Finally `yarn start --dev-client`, and the development server should pop up on your phone, select and run it